# Jmeter-Is this possible to change the processing order

Tags: testing, execution

I am using j meter tool.I have to do three process and do the load testing for the same.

1. Login
2. Add Patient(After login)
3. Logout.

When i run the j meter for 100 users.
It will executed in the following way

1. Login(100 users) is executed fully.

Then only Add patient process is executed.Now my doubt is how to execute in the below order

1. Login(1),Add Patient(1),Logout(1)
2. Login(2),Add Patient(2),Logout(2) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this case is use the Loop Counter and set the loop counter to 1

[image]

The loop counter guarantees that the samplers are executed in a particular order.